# NGINX command make: recipe for target 'build' failed

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-config

After running

```
./configure \
--sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--with-pcre \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
--with-http_ssl_module
```

I ran the command `make` but got this error

> `/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /var/run/nginx`

and

> `Makefile:8: recipe for target 'build' failed`

Comment: What do you mean *After running*? What command is outputting the error? `make`? `make install`?

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer after make

Comment: my bad I'll edit the post

Comment: That's weird; `make` shouldn't yet need to access anywhere outside the project directory.